Sorting array along two dimensions
Suppose you have data in form of a numpy array of shape (100,3). The number 100 represents a number of sensors, for each sensor you have:

x-coordinate (data[:, 0])
y-coordinate (data[:, 1])
reading, e.g. temperature (data[:, 2])

The sensors are not placed on a regular grid. How can I sort the data array such that the x- and y- coordinates are both sequentially sorted? Here is an example:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(100, 3))
x_pos = data[:, 0]
y_pos = data[:, 1]
temperature = data[:, 2]

sorted_ind = np.lexsort((y_pos, x_pos))
sorted_data = data[sorted_ind]

plt.plot(sorted_data[:, 0]) #plot x positions
plt.plot(sorted_data[:, 1]) #plot y positions

From my understanding, both coordinates should now be in ascending order but this is only true for the x position.
EDIT: The goal is to display the data on a grid (which does not have to be regular but sorted correctly). So imagine the temperature sensors are almost evenly distributed somewhere over a square area. But if I read out the exact gps positions, it will not be a perfectly regular grid.
img = data.reshape(10,10,3)
plt.imshow(img[:, :, 2]) #should display the temperature correcly positioned on a grid


When you use np.lexsort((y_pos, x_pos)), it sorts primarily by x_pos and only uses y_pos to break ties when x_pos values are identical. This does not ensure that y_pos will be sequentially sorted independently of x_pos.

I'm not sure what you mean by both x and y coordinates being sequentially sorted. The can't be both sequentially sorted at the same time. Either you sort by one, and where points match you sort by the other, or you sort by some other criteria (ie. distance from 0,0)

Showing example data and plots and pointing out the problem in them would be good.
